# Split string into 2D array

Tags: c#

I have .txt file with 10 954 lines in the format of `6,4:10`

I need to load that .txt file with `StreamReader` and split every line at `':'` into 2D array.

To look like this

```
[6,4 10]
[5,2 15]
[9,3 20]
```

So i can later on count each column and place it in a particular category.

This is the furthest i got so far

```
StreamReader ulaz = new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\Core\\Desktop\\podaciC.txt");

string[] polje = new string[10954];

while (!ulaz.EndOfStream)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < polje.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        polje[i] = ulaz.ReadLine();
    }
}
ulaz.Close();

foreach (string s in polje)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: I'm still new here, i'll add it to the main post what i've done so far

Comment: The code you provided looks likes it's just trying to print the contents of the .txt. file. This is pretty far from what your goal is, so you should at least try to explain some of your thought processes or theories on the problem.

Comment: How do you separate 10954 strings of 6,4:10 from each other?

Comment: @TimonPost I think it's 10954 *lines*, each with the format `X,Y:Z`

Comment: Oke, than I will give my answer a change

Comment: @Ivan.S. The output you show does not represent a 2D array. Can you please clarify what the first and second dimensions would be? For example, if the string is `"6,4:10"`, What would your array actually look like when created with a single item? To me it looks like you are saying it should be: `array[0,0] = "6,4", array[0,1] = "10"`? Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

Here is documentation for the **ReadLine()** method of the StreamReader: https://msdn.microsoft.com/da-dk/library/system.io.streamreader.readline(v=vs.110).aspx

Here is documentation for the **Split()** method of the String: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx

You can solve this using those methods.

I would provide code, but that wouldn't be ethical since you haven't indicated that you've tried to solve this problem. I can help you solve your homework, but I won't solve it for you.

Answer (score 0):

My example file uses these strings in it one string on each line:

```
6,4:10 
6,4:10 
6,4:10 
6,4:10
```

**Use Linq to get all lines and split them based on `:`**

1. Get all lines and every line will be represented by a string all lines make up one array of strings
2. then select these result and split the string by and `:` on every index of the string array (lines).
3. Convert the the IEnumerable of string[] to array

   ```
    string[][] array = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\t\\My File2.txt")
           .Select(x => x.Split(':'))
           .ToArray();
   ```

**Out putting values to the console:**

```
        int counter = 0;
        foreach (var rows in array)
        {
            foreach (var number in rows)
            {
                Console.Write("Number row {0} =  {1}\t", counter, number);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            counter++;
        }
```

**How the array looks:**

```
    string[4][]
    {
        string[2] { [0] => 6,4  [1] => 10 }
        string[2] { [0] => 6,4  [1] => 10 }
        string[2] { [0] => 6,4  [1] => 10 }
        string[2] { [0] => 6,4  [1] => 10 }
    }
```

**Console Output**

```
Number row 0 =  6,4     Number row 0 =  10
Number row 1 =  6,4     Number row 1 =  10
Number row 2 =  6,4     Number row 2 =  10
Number row 3 =  6,4     Number row 3 =  10
```

Comment: I read the question to mean that each number group was already on it's own line in the file

Answer (score 0):

No need to fight with arrays and `StreamReader`. Easy to understand example:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            var filePath = "C:\\Users\\Core\\Desktop\\podaciC.txt";

            var result = new List<KeyValuePair<decimal, int>> (11000); // create list with initial capacity

            var lines = File.ReadLines (filePath); // allows to read file line by line (without loading entire file into memory)

            foreach (var line in lines)
            {
                string[] splittedLine = line.Split (':'); // split line into array of two elements

                decimal key = decimal.Parse (splittedLine[0]); // parse first element
                int value = int.Parse (splittedLine[1]);       // parse second element

                var kvp = new KeyValuePair<decimal, int> (key, value); // create tuple

                result.Add (kvp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I suggest you to create custom class like `LineParser` or something which will handle errors for invalid lines etc.